# How to redirect all traffic from clients of openvpn into the socks5?

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I've configured openvpn fully as udp port.
The openvpn network address is 10.8.0.0.
And I've set up the redsocks proxy like followings.

```
base {
 log_debug = on;
 log_info = on;
 log = "stderr";
 daemon = off;
 redirector = iptables;
}

redsocks {
    // Local IP listen to
    local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
    // Port to listen to
    local_port = 31338;
    ip = 127.0.0.1;
    port = 31337;
    // Proxy type
    type = socks5;
}
```

And I've setup the route for outgoing port 31337.

The problem is that I'm going to redirect all incoming packets from openvpn client into redsocks proxy.
I've configured iptables, but not working.
What essential did I missed?

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDSOCKS   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
REDSOCKS   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
REDSOCKS   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:socks
REDSOCKS   udp  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDSOCKS   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner UID match user0

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain REDSOCKS (5 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             0.0.0.0/8
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/8
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             localhost/8
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             link-local/16
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             172.16.0.0/12
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             192.168.0.0/16
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             base-address.mcast.net/4
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             240.0.0.0/4
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             redir ports 31338
```

If I run curl in local, redsocks proxy receive the packets and process them.
But if I run the curl in the openvpn client, redsocks didn't receive the packets.

Please help me.
ps: I've also added `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`, but still now working.